# Pushing a branch to a private repo

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-push

I'm commenting some code and adding things like requirements files to it. I've cloned the repo, branched to a "documenting" branch, completed my documentation and am trying to push to the remote using:

```
git push origin documenting
```

I get an error:

```
 ==> git push origin documenting 
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://myurl/myrepo.git/' not found
```

Browsing to `https://myurl/myrepo.git/` shows me the repo, so my URL is correct.

I tried the same command with a public repo I setup and it works. When the command is used successfully I can browse to my repo and see the new `documenting` branch in there with my changes.

What is the best way to fix this error? It seems like a permissions issue. Should I request permission, or is there something else I can try instead?

Comment: Mmm the url is a bit weird, I wonder if it's just a typo. What shows up if you type `git remote -v`?

Comment: I see the repo. `'https://myurl/myrepo.git/'` has my real URL and the real repo name changed out. But I see the same thing for the working public repo.

Comment: Sorry, no idea, have you tried to create the branch on the actual repo via UI and pushing afterwards?

Comment: I would, but I'm trying to understand how it works on a public repo fine and not in this repo that I'm trying to contribute to first. FWIW, I cannot do a pull either.

Comment: mmmh, maybe it IS related to permissions, have you cloned the repo via console?

Comment: Yes, I did clone via console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and compare the output of git remote -v executed in the local clone of both the private and the public repo.

The fact that you cannot even do a `git pull` (meaning a `git fetch` + a merge) means the url associated with that private repo is somehow incorrect.

Try setting it back

```
git remote set-url origin https://myurl/myrepo.git
```

(no trailing slash there)

Try also a simple `git ls-remote https://myurl/myrepo.git` (again, no trailing slash) from any folder you want, to see if the remote access works.

Comment: `git ls-remote https://myurl/myrepo.git` shows the references available.

Comment: I've used `git remote set-url origin https://myurl/myrepo.git` and it now works. I have no idea why though. Comparing the output from a `git remote -v` prior give identical repo names. Thanks for helping me, I've marked your suggestion as the answer.